# display validation error massage in view laravel

Tags: laravel

I try to display validation **error** massage in view from **`store function`** and **`update function`** ,
i put "*add inputs*" and "*edit input*" in the same view
so i can't know which function has validation error

this is my function **store** code ...

```
$rules = [
         'section_name' => 'required|min:3',
         'section_pic' => 'image',
         ];

$customMessages = [
                  'section_name.required' => 'Please Enter Section Name ',
                  'section_name.min' => 'Section Name Must Be At Least 3 Character ',
                  'section_pic.image'  => 'You Should Choose Images Only',
                  ];

 $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

  here some add code .....

 return redirect('/Sections')->with('success_store','Success ! Your Section Added Successfully');
```

and this is my function **update** code ...

```
$rules = [
         'section_name' => 'required|min:3',
         'section_pic' => 'image',
         ];

$customMessages = [
                  'section_name.required' => 'Enter Section Name You Want To Update to',
                  'section_name.min' => 'To Update Section Name Must Be At Least 3 Character ',
                  'section_pic.image'  => 'To Update You Should Choose Images Only',
                  ];

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

some update code .....

return redirect('/Sections')->with('success_update','Success ! Your Section Updated Successfully');
```

and this in my **view** ...

```
@if($errors->any())
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openModal() {
            $("#section_add").modal("show");
        }
        window.onload = openModal;
    </script>
@endif

@if($errors->any())
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openModal() {
            $("#section_edit").modal("show");
        }
        window.onload = openModal;
    </script>
@endif
```

this my **add inputs** in add modal ...

```
<input type="text" name="section_name" class="form-control name"
value="{{ old('section_name') }}" autofocus required>

@error('section_name')
<small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
@enderror
```

and this my **edit inputs** in edit modal ...

```
<input type="text" name="section_name" class="form-control name"
value="{{ old('section_name') }}" autofocus required>

@error('section_name')
<small class="text-danger">{{ $message }}</small>
@enderror
```

Comment: What validation error are you getting?

Comment: i get the same error in both modal ... for example when i add section , the validation error display in both modal (add modal) and (edit modal) , and the same happen when i edit section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest solutions to your problem would be to use [named error bags](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#named-error-bags). You can [manually create the validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#manually-creating-validators) via `Validator::make()`..

So, ideally you should modify your controller logic like so,( I will just write one of the methods as an example then you can copy same logic in the other method)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

  $rules = [
    'section_name' => 'required|min:3',
    'section_pic' => 'image',
   ];

  $customMessages = [
    'section_name.required' => 'Please Enter Section Name ',
    'section_name.min' => 'Section Name Must Be At Least 3 Character ',
    'section_pic.image'  => 'You Should Choose Images Only',
  ];

 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $customMessages);

 if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('Sections/create')
                    ->withErrors($validator,'store') // or whatever key you give
                    ->withInput();
    }
  return redirect('/Sections')->with('success_store','Success ! Your Section Added Successfully');
}
```

In your views you can now grab errors with specified key i.e. in this case store,
`{{ $errors->store->all() }}`. Hope that helps

Comment: when i try your code , it accept data and submitted and ignore validation error rule

Comment: validation rule min:3 , when i enter 1 character it add in database and get error massage

Comment: Make sure that the keys in `$rules` are exactly the same as you are sending from your form. i.e. `section_name` & `section_pic` etc..otherwise post your form code